# How to navigate one folder up from current file path?

Tags: c#

I need to navigate one folder up from the current path of a file and save the same file there. How can I strip one level from the directory path? Thank you!

`C:\Users\stacy.zim\AppData\Local\Temp\ICLocal\e53486af-7e5e-4c54-b9dc-d15cb55f3f55.pdf`

The file will be saved to below.

`C:\Users\stacy.zim\AppData\Local\Temp\e53486af-7e5e-4c54-b9dc-d15cb55f3f55.pdf`

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I don't have a problem with the question (it clearly states what is needed, unlike many others), but it always surprises me how few people know of/use the `Path` class.

Comment: @vesan on other had basic stuff like the fact that "parent directory" defined as  ".." in the path is probably more of lore than documentation... So yes, `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(source, @"..\newFileName.ext"))` could not be ever discovered.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm actually surprised that it's not a constant (like the `DirectorySeparatorChar`). I added a note about this approach to my answer.

Comment: you can use `string.split`, remove one item and then `string.join`. This is easy. Google it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually it is called Parent for "One Folder Up"

[`System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Method 1 Get by file
var file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\stacy.zim\AppData\Local\Temp\ICLocal\e53486af-7e5e-4c54-b9dc-d15cb55f3f55.pdf");
var parentDir = file.Directory == null ? null : file.Directory.Parent; // null if root
if (parentDir != null)
{
    // Do something with Path.Combine(parentDir.FullName, filename.Name);
}
```

[`System.IO.Directory.GetParent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Method 2 Get by path
var parentDir = Directory.GetParent(@"C:\Users\stacy.zim\AppData\Local\Temp\ICLocal\");
```

Answer (score 9):

```
string path = @"C:\Users\stacy.zim\AppData\Local\Temp\ICLocal\e53486af-7e5e-4c54-b9dc-d15cb55f3f55.pdf"
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path); //without file name
string oneUp = Path.GetDirectoryName(directory); // Temp folder
string fileOneUp = Path.Combine(oneUp, Path.GetFileName(path));
```

Just be careful if the original file is in root folder - then the `oneUp` will be `null` and `Path.Combine` will throw an exception.

Edit:

In the code above, I split the commands on separate lines for clarity. It could be done in one line:

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)), Path.GetFileName(path));
```

Or, as @AlexeiLevenkov suggest, you can use `..` to go up one directory. In that case, you could do:

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), @"..\"+Path.GetFileName(path));
```

which will give you the `..` in your path - if you don't want that, run `Path.GetFullPath` on the result. Again, you need to be careful if your original file is in the root folder - unlike the first approach, which will throw an exception, this will just give you the same path.

Comment: Thank you, everything else caused problems