# Navigate back a folder in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# WPF app and I need to get the path of the file. I was having trouble using `Path.GetDirectory()` and since the `exe` can be copied anywhere, I ended up using the following to get the path:

```
string currentPath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
```

In this, I would like to be able to up in from this path but I can't. I've tried using:

```
var homeFolder = Path.Combine(currentPath, @"..\Home");
```

but it doesn't work and just adds `Home` to the `currentPath`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate one folder up from current file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991331/how-to-navigate-one-folder-up-from-current-file-path)

Comment: "I was having trouble using Path.GetDirectory()". What problems do you have? That is the easiest way. You can call it twice to get the parent directory and combine with 'Home'.